# Getting connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 when attempting HTTP request

Tags: node.js, http, post, get, request

> I am attempting to make a http request to news.google.com using the native node.js `http` module.  I am getting the `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80` error when I tried the following

```
var http = require('http');

var payload = JSON.stringify({
    name: 'John Smith',
    email: 'john.smith@smith.com',
    resume: 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=asgsaegsehsehseh'
});

var options = {
    hostname: 'https://news.google.com',
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
};

var httpRequest = http.request(options, function(request, response) {
    console.log('STATUS', response.statusCode);
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('BODY:', chunk);
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log('No more data in response');
    });
});

httpRequest.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Error with the request:', e.message);
});

httpRequest.write(payload);
httpRequest.end();
```

Why am I getting this error?

I tried using the `request` npm module.  And it worked!

Answer (score 102):

In my case, issue was actually default behaviour of HTTP client that I was using, `axios`.

By default, axios redirects us to `127.0.0.1:80` if it doesn't find requested URL or `http` method(GET/POST/PUT). So better check your URL if are also using `axios`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. inside server of reactjs (ssr.tsx) the Axios url was not correct.

Comment: If you're using nextjs, and using the same function to fetch data on client side and server side using relative url, it might not work on the server side. You need to give an absolute path on the server side. On client side, Axios automatically gets window url.

Answer (score 72):

My problem was while using `supertest` and `jest`. My mistake was not putting "/" as a prefix to some url. So, double check if the url for the request you are making is proper.

Comment: Had the same experience. Forgot a leading '/' before doing the request with `supertest` and `jest`. Dziekuje bardzo.

Comment: for some weird reason, this works for me. thank God and stack overflow.

Comment: I missed the leading "/" myself. This helped. Thanks

Comment: I had the leading `/` but mistakenly also had an unnecessary  `.`. Thank you!

Comment: I made the same mistake, This helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Mine was the same. Thanks a lot

Comment: this saved me hours of debugging...

Answer (score 10):

I'm using axios and this error occurred with `get` request, solved it by adding `http://` before my URL (in my case the server is http)

Answer (score 6):

There are several issues here:

1. The `hostname` field of the `options` structure should be just the host, not a URL. In your case it should just be `'news.google.com'`.
2. The signature for the callback to the `request` method is `function (response)` -- yours is `function (request, response)`. Lose the first parameter.
3. As written this will aways return an HTTP redirection to the https site. Replace `var http = require('http');` with `var https = require('https');` and then use `https` everywhere instead of `http`.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue while using **supertest** and **jest**. I made the mistake of using `./users` instead of `/users` as the url.

Comment: Its common mistake when you give wrong path

Comment: Its common issue when we use wrong path in http calls

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with **jest** and **supertest**. Just changed `api/blogs` to `/api/blogs` and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Solve it by fixing the HTTP request path mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and my solution (That might not be the same for most people) was that the server was not listening yet, I had to call the axios function after.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

store the root url in some variable or environtment and append it before request
so instead of
axios.get('/api/myurl')
do something like
let baseUrl = 'https://google.com"

axios.get(baseUrl + '/api/myurl')

Answer (score 0):

Another cause for this error could be that in your code, you might be referring to an environment variable as:

```
const localhostUrl = process.env.LOCALHOST_URL;
```

Whilst, not having this variable defined, (as expected), in your .env file as:

```
LOCALHOST_URL = http://localhost:8000/
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error when when using supertest and jest. fix was adding prefix "/" to the url.

Answer (score 0):

This error could also be caused by a prerender error according to Next.js 13 [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error).

In my case, I was assuming all values existed, instead of setting a fallback value which should be null.

So I changed:

```
{articles.map((article) => {
return (
<div key = {article.id}>
<h1>{article.title}</>
</>
)
})}
```

TO:

```
{articles ? articles.map((article) => {
return (
<div key = {article.id}>
<h1>{article.title}</>
</>
)
}): null}
```

Unfortunately, this error did not show up at build time, it showed only after deploying to Vercel.